# How can I make a string appear in a certain location from localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <button id = "customizations" button onclick = "loadsaved()" title = "Load">L</button>
  <div id = "text" contenteditable = "true"></div>
</html>

<script>
function loadsaved() {

 let stringValue = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
 let y = localStorage.getItem("savetext");

}
</script>
```

What I want is, when I press the button, it'll load the string that was saved in local storage in that div text box. How can I achieve this?

Comment: _"The Element property `innerHTML` gets **or sets** the HTML or XML markup contained within the element."_

Comment: What button?  Are we missing some markup.

Comment: @Keith I didn't add the button since I didn't see a reason for adding it since all people need is the function of the button. But for the sake of the cause, I edited my question and added the code of it.

Comment: your buttons markup is wrong. Use this
`<button id = "customizations" type="button" onclick = "loadsaved()" title = "Load">L</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the answer almost: here ia a little modification

```
function loadsaved() {

 document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("savetext");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =localStorage.getItem("savetext");`